# Laravel and Eloquent saving relationship on the hasOne side

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

Ok, working in Laravel with eloquent so i have the concept of a `ContentType` model and a `Template` model. I have a form where you set data for the Content Type and you select from a drop down list of templates which one is to be associated with the content type. My models look like this:

ContentType:

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use \Hyn\Tenancy\Traits\UsesTenantConnection;

class ContentType extends Model
{
    use UsesTenantConnection;

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'parent_content_id', 'name', 'description', 'is_requestable', 'status',
    ];

    /**
     * Get the template that owns the content type.
     */
    public function template()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Template');
    }

    /**
     * Get the entity groups for the content type.
     */
    public function entity_groups()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\EntityGroup');
    }

    /**
     * Get the entities for the content type.
     */
    public function entities()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Entity');
    }
}
```

Template:

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use \Hyn\Tenancy\Traits\UsesTenantConnection;

class Template extends Model
{
    use UsesTenantConnection;

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'name', 'filename', 'status',
    ];

    /**
     * Get the content types for the template.
     */
    public function content_types()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\ContentType');
    }
}
```

What i want to do is store or update the template value. Is there a way of doing this straight off of . the `ContentType` model instead of saving that relationship through the `Template` model? Or should i adjust the types of relationship i have in the first place?

Comment: Can u explain more of what u want? U say u want to update template? and isn't it like `$template->update([])`?.

Comment: @ako, I want to update the relationship between the content type and the template. Is essence, i have a column on content table for `template_id` and that is the data i'd like to update. I have am updating other . attributes of `content_type` so i wanted to see if i could do that without looking up and making a SQL call to get the template. Can i update just the content type record? I am new to Laravel and Eloquent so maybe i'm framing this problem the wrong way. I'd just like to not have to get a template object instantiated if i don't need to if that makes sense.

Comment: There are nicer ways of doing it, yes. But behind the scenes, it will still execute a query on the `templates` table. So, if I understand correctly, you just want to know how to do it through relationships (which is probably the nicer way of doing it)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do it like this:

```
$contentType->template()->update([
    'colToBeUpdated' => 'new value',
]);
```

This will execute 1 query to update the `template` of the `$contentType`.

But if you just want to change the `template_id` (to associate `$contentType` with some other template) you could just do:

```
$contentType->template()->associate($newId);
```

Or

```
$contentType->update(['template_id' => $newId]);
```

Comment: I guess my question then becomes, why does `template` have to be touched at all if essentially all i'm doing is changing the `template_id` column on the `content_types` table? Also, if i need to change my relationships so that i can just update the `template_id` column on the `content_types` table record i'm fine with doing that.

Comment: It doesn't need to be touched. My understanding was that you want to update some unrelated columns on the related template. You could always just do `$contentType->template_id = $newValue` and leave `templates` table untouched.

Comment: @ryanpitts1 There, I updated the answer to reflect this. Let me know if that's what you were looking for.

Comment: @devk Note that `associate()` doesn't actually save the record, so you still have to call `$contentType->save()` after the `associate()` (or, just append `->save()` onto the call chain since `associate()` will return the `$contentType` value anyway).